# php function get two optional argument and write where class

Tags: php, mysql

i have one function which calculate total number of records in table and get two arguments and both are optional.

```
function getTotal($id=0,$id1=0)
    {
        ($id==0?$addQuery="":$addQuery=" where art_id=".$id);
        if($id1<>0 && $id==0)
        {
        $addQuery=" where up_type=".$id1
        }
        if($id1<>0 && $id<>0)
        {
        $addQuery=" and up_type=".$id1
        }
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
        $query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_up ".$addQuery;
        $result=$this->query($query,1);
        return $result;
    }
```

if you see i write if id is passed then i put the where class in one line

but if 2nd argument id1 is passed or not i need to add text to where class, but here is if id is passed then it should start from **and** and if id is not passed it should start with **where**

i try to write if but these lines are too much, i need some thing like first line

```
($id==0?$addQuery="":$addQuery=" where art_id=".$id);
```

for 2nd agrument.

Thanks

Comment: this looks like an SQL-injection hole, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getTotal($id=0,$id1=0)
{
    $addQuery="where 1=1"
    if($id <>0)  $addQuery.=" and art_id =".$id
    if($id1<>0)  $addQuery.=" and up_type=".$id1

    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    $query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_up ".$addQuery;
    $result=$this->query($query,1);
    return $result;
}
```

this is a generic way to have multiple cases tested

Comment: you're missing the `WHERE` clause

Comment: -1, if you forget to (single) quote the injected `$id`'s id's that contain spaces will not work, also anti-SQL injection measures you take prior to this snipped will fail.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getTotal($id=0,$id1=0)
    {
        $where = array();
        if ($id) $where[]='`art_id`="'.$id.'"';
        if ($id1) $where[] = '`up_type`="'.$id1.'"';
        $where = (!count($where) ? '' : 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where));
            $query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_up ".$where;
            mysql_set_charset('utf8');
            $result=$this->query($query,1);
            return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
function getTotal($id = 0,$id1 = 0) {
  // sorry, I rewrite the first expression to this, easier to read IMHO
  $addQuery = $id == 0 ? "" : " where art_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'";
  if ($id1 <> 0)
    $addQuery .= ($id == 0 ? " where" : " and") . " up_type='".mysql_real_escape_string($id1)."'";
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');
  $query="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_up ".$addQuery;
  $result=$this->query($query,1);
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: -1, if you forget to (single) quote the injected $id's id's that contain spaces will not work, also anti-SQL injection measures you take prior to this snipped will fail. – Johan in 0 seconds edit

Comment: please don't downvote because of something that OP didn't ask. I gave answer to what he wanted to do, period. that injection thing should be another topic.

Comment: I downvoted because it would be dangerous to use this code in production. If you edited the post to not be dangerous I'll be more than happy to upvote.